# Maven, Jersey and Hibernate - No Persistence provider for Entity Manager named x

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa

Currently creating a RestFul web service with a database attached but whenever I run my method, I get the error.

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named kevinsdb
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:61)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    at Music.Assignment.persistence.PersistenceUtil.<clinit>(PersistenceUtil.java:18)
```

I think it has something to do with my pom.xml file.

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>Music</groupId>
    <artifactId>App</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>App</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>App</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>**</include>
        </includes>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
   </resource>
   </resources>

    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.0-Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-binding</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        -->

        <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.26</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Also here is my persistence.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<persistence-unit name="kevinsdb" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"> 
<!-- 
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider> 
 -->      
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />

        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/kevinsdb" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="root" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</property>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider" />             
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.minPoolSize" value="0" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.maxPoolSize" value="25" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.maxConnectionAge" value="14400" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.maxIdleTime" value="100" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

As I said, I don't know if I need to add certain things to my pom.xml file. Any help would be appreciated.

Also, I know this is covered a lot but I've tried everything else on SO and no joy.

Comment: Try uncommenting the line <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

Comment: @SimonMartinelli does nothing, its something to do with the pom.xml

Comment: where do you deploy your war file?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I deploy via wildfly in eclipse

Comment: But then you should use transaction-type="TRANSACTION" and use a DataSource and don't create the db connection in the properties. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am having the same issue and can't solve it

Comment: @SimonMartinelli What do you mean by use a DataSource? How do you do that?

Comment: Have a look at the docs: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/DataSource+configuration